# How to filter objects by array in object? AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I get many objects from my database which has the following structure:

```
$scope.user = {
    "surname" : "Kowalsky",
    "name" : "Jan",
    "subject_id" : ["123","678"]
}
```

I need to display all users (surnames and names) which have "123" in the `subject_id` array.

I tried to do it in `ng-repeat` but it doesn't work.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList  | filter: {user.subject_id:'123'}">
  <b>Surname: </b>{{user.surname}}
  <b>Name: </b>{{user.name}}
</div>
```

Also, I tried it in the controller but it also didn't work:

```
$scope.userFilter = $filter('filter')($scope.users.subject_id: '123')[0];
```

Comment: did you try any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use a controller function in your template like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList  | filter: filterUser">
```

And declare the function 'filterUser' in your controller:

```
$scope.filterUser = function(item) {
   if(item.subject_id.indexOf('123') != -1}) {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remember, your variable userList is array.

```js
app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("AppController", function($scope){
    $scope.userList = [
        {
            "surname" : "Kowalsky",
            "name" : "Jan",
            "subject_id" : ["123","678"]
        },{
            "surname" : "Carlos",
            "name" : "Fev",
            "subject_id" : ["344","67"]
        },{
            "surname" : "Joao",
            "name" : "Mar",
            "subject_id" : ["112","634"]
        }
    ];
}).filter('filterBySubject', function() {
    return function(userList, filter) {
        var result = [];
        
        for(var i in userList){
            if(userList[i].subject_id.indexOf(filter) > -1){
                result.push(userList[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppController">
<div ng-repeat="user in userList  | filterBySubject:'123'">
  <b>Surname: </b>{{user.surname}}
  <b>Name: </b>{{user.name}}
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize e.g. [lodash](https://lodash.com/) that helps you work with collections.
Then you could prefilter your collection easily, in you controller as

```
$scope.users = _.filter($scope.users, function(user) {
  return _.includes(user.subject_id, '123');
});
```